# .htaccess cross-domain redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to create a redirect from `http://example.com/links/AAA`  to `http://links.example.net/l/AAA` (where `AAA` is a variable). I've got that working. The problem is that both `http://example.com/links/` and `http://example.com/links` should redirect to `http://links.example.net` (without the `/l/`).

At the moment `http://example.com/links/` redirects to `http://links.example.net/l/`, and `example.com/links` redirects to `http://links.example.net/l//hsphere/local/home/username/example.com/links`.

Current `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://links.example.net/l/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Pseudocode:

```
if ($path) {
    goto(http://links.example.net/l/${path}/); // Adding the trailing slash is not necessary, but would be handy. Obviously, don't add if it already exists.
} else {
    goto(http://links.example.net/);
}
```

I have looked through a bunch of other `.htaccess` questions here (good grief there are so many), but have yet to find anything equivalent.

If necessary, I can do this a different way:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php/$1
</IfModule>
```

And then do the redirection in PHP, where I'm a bit more at home. But that would be (a) less efficient, (b) less fun, and (c) less educational. So I'm going to try to do this the proper way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way, assuming that your .htaccess file is in the root directory of your site.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

#if /links or links/ (path empty)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/links/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://links.example.net [R=301,L]

#otherwise
RewriteRule ^links/(.*)$ http://links.example.net/l/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that first thing tomorrow morning and report back to you.